# Setup CentOS webserver with internal network, but dedicated external IP

Tags: networking, centos, local-area-network, server-setup

- I have 2 servers on 2 networks, with both their own WAN ip (x.x.192.196 and x.x.192.200).
- Both servers are physically next to each other
- As office, we are working in network x.x.192.196, with desktop computers and this only server. This internal network range is at 192.168.2.x.
- The server on x.x.192.200 has 2 Gbit network cards
- Both networks are connected through our officebuilding 50/50 firewall
- Internal networks are Gbit networks
- server on x.x.192.200 is a CentOS webserver (with Virtualbox and DirectAdmin installed)
- We have to connect from any computer in x.x.192.196 to x.x.192.200 via the hostname.

How to get the fastest (Gbit) connection from one network to the other if you are working in the office?

Current network settings of CentOS on x.x.192.200 are:

```
# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3 
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=static
DEFROUTE=yes
IPADDR=x.x.192.200
GATEWAY=x.x.192.193
NETMASK=255.255.255.240
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=8.8.4.4
NM_CONTROLLED=no
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=no
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME=enp0s3
UUID=023dfae5-623b-45ea-9a44-dxxxxxxxx
DEVICE=enp0s3
ONBOOT=yes
```

So the setup should be as follows:

```
- Webserver CentOS --------------- WAN:] x.x.192.200              ]
|                                      ]                          ]
internal network 192.168.2.x           ]-office building firewall ]- world
|                                      ]                          ]
- Mac server           ]               ]                          ]
- other office PC's    ] --------- WAN:] x.x.192.196              ]
```